# Converting vector of char type to data frame in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, character

I have created a vector of character type.

```
Browse[2]> a <- c("iris")     
Browse[2]> a
[1] "iris"
Browse[2]> class(a)
[1] "character"
```

Now I want to somehow take a value out of this character value "iris" and convert it to dataframe. Since we know iris is valid data frame so it must print value of iris dataframe. In other words I want to make "iris" to iris as dataframe

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `get`? Like `myDf <- get("iris")`.

Comment: Is `data.frame("iris")` what you are looking for?